# I am getting extra double quotes on XML parsed dictionary using SOAP Engine

Tags: ios, xcode, soap, xml-parsing

I'm using SOAPEngine in my application and im having some problems in parsing xml data. I am getting this before my output "Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future." 
the SOAP request i call is

```
soap = [[SOAPEngine alloc] init];
soap.delegate = self;
soap.actionNamespaceSlash = YES;
soap.authorizationMethod = SOAP_AUTH_CUSTOM;
soap.header = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<userCredentials xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><userName>swm</userName><passWord>swm123</passWord></userCredentials>"];
[soap setValue:@"6" forKey:@"staffId"];
[soap requestURL:@"http://swm20.evizontech.com/mobApp_WebServices/ws_getTaskListByAssignee.asmx"
      soapAction:@"http://tempuri.org/GetTaskAssignedToMeList"];
```

my output and XML for web service is shown in screen shot attached. Actual problem is i am getting extra double quotes on XML parsed NSdictionary. How can i solve this?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in SOAPEngine, it was fixed in newer versions

Answer (score 0):

Is an internal warning message, only internal warning message, during the conversion of the received data in an readable XML format, you can ignore it, it is a not blocking error and not generate others errors on the received data, this message has been removed in new versions